# code is outputting location of array rather than the array itself

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

here's the code:

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.Math;

public class ArrayFunHouseTwo
 {
   public static int[] getCountValuesBiggerThanX(int[] numArray, int count, int x)
{
    int[] newNumArray = new int[0];
    //int num = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    int z = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < numArray.length; y++){
        if(numArray[y] > x && z < count){
            newNumArray = new int[count];
            newNumArray[z] = numArray[y];
            z++;
        }


    }

    //}
    return newNumArray;
}
}
```

and it's associated runner class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab14b
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    int[] one = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int[] two = {1,2,3,9,11,20,30};
    //add more test cases
    int[] three = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2};
    int[] four = {3,6,9,12,15,18,21,23,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,0};
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(four));
        System.out.println("first 7 values greater than 9  " +      ArrayFunHouseTwo.getCountValuesBiggerThanX(four, 7, 9));
    System.out.println("first 5 values greater than 15  " +    ArrayFunHouseTwo.getCountValuesBiggerThanX(four, 5, 15));
}
}
```

and as I said above, it's outputting the location, I think that's what it is, instead of the array itself.

i.e. I'm getting: first 7 values greater than 9  [I@38f0b51d

first 5 values greater than 15  [I@4302a01f

instead of first 7 values greater than 9  [12, 15, 18, 21, 23, 19, 17]

first 5 values greater than 15  [18, 21, 23, 19, 17]

**UPDATE**

ok, so now I'm getting:

> first 7 values greater than 9  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17]
>
> first 5 values greater than 15  [0, 0, 0, 0, 17]

Comment: You can't make `newNumArray` a `new int[]` every time you find an element; you have to know the length of the array beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the return value of your function to a string with `Arrays.toString`

```
 System.out.println("first 7 values greater than 9  " +    Arrays.toString(ArrayFunHouseTwo.getCountValuesBiggerThanX(four, 7, 9)));
    System.out.println("first 5 values greater than 15  " +    Arrays.toString(ArrayFunHouseTwo.getCountValuesBiggerThanX(four, 5, 15)));
```

As to your new problem, you dont want to do `newNumArray = new int[count];` so deep in the loop, its getting overwritten every time.

My java is rusty, but perhaps you can set `newNumArray` to `null` instead, in the first line, and only recreate it inside the loop if it is `null`. Or just new it once directly to the final size.. depends on what you want to output.

Comment: ok, that works but I've got a related issue, check my update in the OP

Comment: I got it, I moved 'newNumArray = new int[count]` to the very top of the method before the for loop and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to call this method when building Strings:

```
Arrays.toString(array);
```

When an object is added to a String, its toString() method is invoked.
Sadly, for arrays, this prints the garbage you are seeing (it's not actually garbage, but it is about as useful)

Change your code to this:

```
System.out.println("first 5 values greater than 15  " +    
    Arrays.toString(ArrayFunHouseTwo.getCountValuesBiggerThanX(four, 5, 15)));
```

Comment: that's what I have, isn't it? when I put `Arrays.toString(four)`

Comment: ok, that works but I've got a related issue, check my update in the OP

Comment: So you've got a bug... different question entirely: Ask a new question.